# jQuery Dropdownchecklist Select Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdownchecklist

I'm using the jQuery [dropdownchecklist control](http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html) and I'm trying to figure out a way to select the first item in the list on a button click. Unfortunately, there isn't a lot of documentation on the control.

Some people suggested using the `[id] options` selector to loop through the items in the list. This is what I tried:

```
$("#<%=ddlMyOptions.ClientID %> option").each(function(item){
    if(item == 0){
        $(this).attr("selected", true);
    }
});
```

When I run this, I notice that originally `$(this).attr("selected")` returns the literal value "selected". It seems like however, changing it to "true" doesn't actually take effect since if I run `$(this).attr("selected")` immediately after `$(this).attr("selected", true);` in my immediate window, it still reports the literal value instead of `true`. Am I doing this wrong? Is there a better way to select an item in the list?

Comment: Can you provide all the code HTML, CSS, or a DEMO / sample, etc.?

Comment: Hmm I can't create a jsfiddle, there are some dependencies it can't resolve...

Answer (score 0):

You would have to select the first item in the `select` element before initializing the `dropdownchecklist`:

```
$("#<%=ddlMyOptions.ClientID %> option").first().prop('selected',true).parent().dropdownchecklist();
```

**UPDATE**

To select the first item in the `dropdownchecklist` once it has been initialized use:

```
$(function() {
    $('button').on('click',function() {
        $("#ddcl-<%=ddlMyOptions.ClientID %>-i0\\.0").prop('checked',true);
        // OR $('#ddcl-<%=ddlMyOptions.ClientID %>-ddw').find(':checkbox').first().prop('checked',true);
    });
});
```

Comment: `before initializing the dropdownchecklist` it needs to happen when a button is clicked, not when it's being initialized.

Comment: So how do we guess how your application works if you do not provide CSS+HTML or a DEMO? Is the `dropdownchecklist` already initialized when you're clicking the button? What's the button meant for?